# Slowness in query having many nested in clauses

Tags: mysql, in-clause

I am facing slowness in a query having many nested in clauses.

The query is given below:

```
select SA0_.sid as stid from table_starea SA0_ left outer join table_arcons AC1_ on SA0_.acid=AC1_.acid where SA0_.sid in (select SB1_.sid from table_arstaff AC0_ left outer join table_stf SB1_ on AC0_.sid=SB1_.sid left outer join table_stfgr SG2_ on SB1_.sgid=SG2_.sgid where AC0_.acid in (select AC1_.acid from table_starea SA0_ left outer join table_arcons AC1_ on SA0_.acid=AC1_.acid where SA0_.sid in (select SB1_.sid from table_arstaff AC0_ left outer join table_stf SB1_ on AC0_.sid=SB1_.sid left outer join table_stfgr SG2_ on SB1_.sgid=SG2_.sgid where AC0_.acid in (select AC1_.acid from table_starea SA0_ left outer join table_arcons AC1_ on SA0_.acid=AC1_.acid where SA0_.sid in (select SB1_.sid from table_arstaff AC0_ left outer join table_stf SB1_ on AC0_.sid=SB1_.sid left outer join table_stfgr SG2_ on SB1_.sgid=SG2_.sgid where AC0_.acid in (select AC1_.acid from table_starea SA0_ left outer join table_arcons AC1_ on SA0_.acid=AC1_.acid where SA0_.sid in (select SB1_.sid from table_arstaff AC0_ left outer join table_stf SB1_ on AC0_.sid=SB1_.sid left outer join table_stfgr SG2_ on SB1_.sgid=SG2_.sgid where AC0_.acid in (select AC1_.acid from table_starea SA0_ left outer join table_arcons AC1_ on SA0_.acid=AC1_.acid where SA0_.sid in (select SB1_.sid from table_arstaff AC0_ left outer join table_stf SB1_ on AC0_.sid=SB1_.sid left outer join table_stfgr SG2_ on SB1_.sgid=SG2_.sgid where AC0_.acid in (select AC1_.acid from table_starea SA0_ left outer join table_arcons AC1_ on SA0_.acid=AC1_.acid where SA0_.sid in (select SB1_.sid from table_arstaff AC0_ left outer join table_stf SB1_ on AC0_.sid=SB1_.sid left outer join table_stfgr SG2_ on SB1_.sgid=SG2_.sgid where AC0_.acid=19)))))))))));
```

I have checked explain for the same and found like below:

```
+----+--------------+-------------------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table     | partitions | type       | possible_keys                          | key                 | key_len | ref                        | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+--------------+-------------------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE       | <subquery2>   | NULL       | ALL        | NULL                                   | NULL                | NULL    | NULL                       | NULL |   100.00 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE       | SA0_      | NULL       | ref        | table_starea_ix01                      | table_starea_ix01   | 5       | <subquery2>.sid                    |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE       | AC1_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.SA0_.acid                |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | AC0_      | NULL       | ref        | table_arstaff_ix01,tab_attach_fk2      | table_arstaff_ix01  | 4       | const                      |    4 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | SB1_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.AC0_.sid             |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | SG2_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.SB1_.sgid                |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | SA0_      | NULL       | ref        | FKFA890976F203761F,table_starea_ix01   | table_starea_ix01   | 5       | ain2013Realdb.AC0_.sid             |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | AC1_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.SA0_.acid                |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | AC0_      | NULL       | ref        | table_arstaff_ix01,tab_attach_fk2      | table_arstaff_ix01  | 4       | ain2013Realdb.SA0_.acid                |    2 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | SB1_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.AC0_.sid             |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | SG2_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.SB1_.sgid                |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | SA0_      | NULL       | ref        | FKFA890976F203761F,table_starea_ix01   | table_starea_ix01   | 5       | ain2013Realdb.AC0_.sid             |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | AC1_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.SA0_.acid                |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | AC0_      | NULL       | ref        | table_arstaff_ix01,tab_attach_fk2      | table_arstaff_ix01  | 4       | ain2013Realdb.SA0_.acid                |    2 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | SB1_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.AC0_.sid             |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | SG2_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.SB1_.sgid                |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | SA0_      | NULL       | ref        | FKFA890976F203761F,table_starea_ix01   | table_starea_ix01   | 5       | ain2013Realdb.AC0_.sid             |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | AC1_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.SA0_.acid                |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | AC0_      | NULL       | ref        | table_arstaff_ix01,tab_attach_fk2      | table_arstaff_ix01  | 4       | ain2013Realdb.SA0_.acid                |    2 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | SB1_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.AC0_.sid             |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | SG2_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.SB1_.sgid                |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | SA0_      | NULL       | ref        | FKFA890976F203761F,table_starea_ix01   | table_starea_ix01   | 5       | ain2013Realdb.AC0_.sid             |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | AC1_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.SA0_.acid                |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | AC0_      | NULL       | ref        | table_arstaff_ix01,tab_attach_fk2      | table_arstaff_ix01  | 4       | ain2013Realdb.SA0_.acid                |    2 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | SB1_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.AC0_.sid             |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | SG2_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.SB1_.sgid                |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | SA0_      | NULL       | ref        | FKFA890976F203761F,table_starea_ix01   | table_starea_ix01   | 5       | ain2013Realdb.AC0_.sid             |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | AC1_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.SA0_.acid                |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | AC0_      | NULL       | ref        | table_arstaff_ix01,tab_attach_fk2      | table_arstaff_ix01  | 4       | ain2013Realdb.SA0_.acid                |    2 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | SB1_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.AC0_.sid             |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | SG2_      | NULL       | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY             | 4       | ain2013Realdb.SB1_.sgid                |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
+----+--------------+-------------------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

Can anybody suggest a solution to make this query execute fast?

I rewrote the query using INNER JOIN as below:

select SA0_.sid as stid from table_starea SA0_ left outer join table_arcons AC1_ on SA0_.acid=AC1_.acid where SA0_.sid in (select distinct sid from ((select SB1_.sid, AC0_.acid from table_arstaff AC0_ left outer join table_stf SB1_ on AC0_.sid=SB1_.sid left outer join table_stfgr SG2_ on SB1_.sgid=SG2_.sgid) TAB19 INNER JOIN (select acid from ((select AC1_.acid,SA0_.sid from table_starea SA0_ left outer join table_arcons AC1_ on SA0_.acid=AC1_.acid) TAB17 INNER JOIN (select sid from ((select SB1_.sid, AC0_.acid from table_arstaff AC0_ left outer join table_stf SB1_ on AC0_.sid=SB1_.sid left outer join table_stfgr SG2_ on SB1_.sgid=SG2_.sgid) TAB15 INNER JOIN  (select acid from ((select AC1_.acid, SA0_.sid from table_starea SA0_ left outer join table_arcons AC1_ on SA0_.acid=AC1_.acid) TAB13 INNER JOIN (select sid from ((select SB1_.sid, AC0_.acid from table_arstaff AC0_ left outer join table_stf SB1_ on AC0_.sid=SB1_.sid left outer join table_stfgr SG2_ on SB1_.sgid=SG2_.sgid) TAB11 INNER JOIN (select acid from ((select AC1_.acid, SA0_.sid from table_starea SA0_ left outer join table_arcons AC1_ on SA0_.acid=AC1_.acid) TAB9 INNER JOIN (select sid from ((select SB1_.sid, AC0_.acid from table_arstaff AC0_ left outer join table_stf SB1_ on AC0_.sid=SB1_.sid left outer join table_stfgr SG2_ on SB1_.sgid=SG2_.sgid) TAB7 INNER JOIN (select acid from ((select AC1_.acid, SA0_.sid from table_starea SA0_ left outer join table_arcons AC1_ on SA0_.acid=AC1_.acid) TAB5 INNER JOIN (select sid from (select SB1_.sid, AC0_.acid from table_arstaff AC0_ left outer join table_stf SB1_ on AC0_.sid=SB1_.sid left outer join table_stfgr SG2_ on SB1_.sgid=SG2_.sgid) TAB3 INNER JOIN (select acid from (select AC1_.acid, SA0_.sid from table_starea SA0_ left outer join table_arcons AC1_ on SA0_.acid=AC1_.acid) TAB2 INNER JOIN (select SB1_.sid from table_arstaff AC0_ left outer join table_stf SB1_ on AC0_.sid=SB1_.sid left outer join table_stfgr SG2_ on SB1_.sgid=SG2_.sgid where AC0_.acid=19) TAB1 ON TAB2.sid = TAB1.sid) TAB4 on TAB3.acid = TAB4.acid) TAB6 on TAB5.sid = TAB6.sid)) TAB8 ON TAB7.acid = TAB8.acid)) TAB10 on TAB9.sid = TAB10.sid)) TAB12 on TAB11.acid = TAB12.acid)) TAB14 on TAB13.sid = TAB14.sid)) TAB16 on TAB15.acid = TAB16.acid)) TAB18 on TAB17.sid = TAB18.sid)) TAB20 on TAB19.acid = TAB20.acid));

Will this bring optimization?

Comment: Good luck finding someone to wade through all of that!

Comment: Start with a tiny part of the problem. You will be able to scale up the solution to cover your actual problem. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: first: take your last query and get rid of the in (..) expression, then take the next in (..) expression till you have solved them into appropriate join . this should improve you perfomance crucial. (Beside, the outer may be ignored)

Comment: If each table is a sheet of paper, you force mysql to search for entries which are included by your where clause on each sheet first. And then it will join these results with the results of the outer selects. Materialized means, the result of this action/step is persisted in memory as temporary table. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

A first suggestion for performance  ..  each IN clause can easly change in most performance INNER JOIN clause eg for you deeper nested  level you could change  the code

```
    ....
     select AC1_.acid 
                      from table_starea SA0_ 
      left outer join table_arcons AC1_ on SA0_.acid=AC1_.acid 
      where SA0_.sid in ( 
        select SB1_.sid 
        from table_arstaff AC0_ 
        left outer join table_stf SB1_ on AC0_.sid=SB1_.sid 
        left outer join table_stfgr SG2_ on SB1_.sgid=SG2_.sgid 
        where AC0_.acid=19   )

     ....)))))))));
```

with

```
  ......
   select AC1_.acid 
    from table_starea SA0_ 
    left outer join table_arcons AC1_ on SA0_.acid=AC1_.acid 

  ) t2 on AC0_.acid = t2.acid
  INNER JOIN (
    select SB1_.sid 
    from table_arstaff AC0_ 
    left outer join table_stf SB1_ on AC0_.sid=SB1_.sid 
    left outer join table_stfgr SG2_ on SB1_.sgid=SG2_.sgid 
    where AC0_.acid=19 
  ) t1 on t1.sid = SA0_.sid 


      ....)))))))));
```

the resul is the same but the inner join should be more fast  ..

you could start refactoring you code starting from the deeper one and one by one refactor all the IN clause with corresponding INNER JOIN

Comment: I rewrote the query as shown in my question. Will this bring solution to the problem I am facing?

Comment: normally the use of inner join instead of IN clause improve drastically the performance  .. so  ..  compare the two query result and the related  execution time  ..  for a valid check